# How can I have separate trigger and filter conditions in a Django UniqueConstraint?

Tags: django

Given the following models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    pass


class User(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailFIeld(blank=True, default="")

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, ...)
```

I want to enforce the following:

```
IF user has email
    IF user has no customer
        email must be globally unique (i.e. unique in the entire unfiltered users table)
    IF user has customer
        email must be unique within the user's customer
```

I attempted to implement this with two `UniqueConstraint`s:

```
UniqueConstraint(
    name="customer_scoped_unique_email",
    fields=["customer", "email"],
    condition=(
        Q(customer__isnull=False)
        & ~Q(email=None)
    ),
),
UniqueConstraint(
    name="unscoped_unique_email",
    fields=["email"],
    condition=(
        Q(customer=None)
        & ~Q(email=None)
    ),
),
```

Testing has revealed that this still allows a user without a customer to be created with an email identical to an existing user (**with** a customer). My understanding is that this is because `UniqueConstraint.condition` determines both when the unique constraint should be triggered **and** what other records are included in the uniqueness check.

Is there any way to achieve my desired logic **in the database**, ideally in a Django ORM-supported way, and ideally with a `UniqueConstraint` or `CheckConstraint`? This must occur in the database. It's obviously possible in Python, but I want the extra reliability of a database constraint.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve my desired logic **in the database** ...

Yes, you can use triggers (see SQL in the **Triggers** section below).

> ... ideally in a Django ORM-supported way ...

Not within Django ORM, but for PostgreSQL, you could use [`django-pgtrigger`](https://django-pgtrigger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) to define it on models.

> ... and ideally with a `UniqueConstraint` or `CheckConstraint`?

This is not supported at the database level, since partial indexes only contain the rows based on `WHERE`.

## Partial indexes

[UniqueConstraint.condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.condition) has the same database restrictions as [Index.condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes/#django.db.models.Index.condition).

- PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/indexes-partial.html

  > A *partial index* is an index built over a subset of a table; the subset is defined by a conditional expression (called the predicate of the partial index). The index contains entries for only those table rows that satisfy the *predicate*.
- SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html

  > A partial index is an index over a subset of the rows of a table.
  >
  > ... In partial indexes, only some subset of the rows in the table have corresponding index entries.

  > Only rows of the table for which the WHERE clause evaluates to true are included in the index.

## Triggers

Before insert or update on `user` table, check unscoped unique email.

- PostgreSQL trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unscoped_unique_email() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $unscoped_unique_email$
  DECLARE
    is_used_email bool;
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.email IS NOT NULL AND NEW.customer_id IS NULL THEN
        SELECT TRUE INTO is_used_email FROM user WHERE email = NEW.email AND (id != NEW.id OR NEW.id IS NULL);
        IF is_used_email IS NOT NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unscoped_unique_email"'
            USING DETAIL = format('Key (email)=(%s) already exists.', NEW.email);
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$unscoped_unique_email$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER unscoped_unique_email BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON user
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unscoped_unique_email();
```